# Page Load measurement for React SPA

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, performance-testing, page-load-time

I am looking for a way to measure Page load time and different matrix for React SPA.

I have googled for the same and found some tools like Boomerang etc.

Can any one suggest me any available tools for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Boomerang measures using the History API to detect route changes, and then waiting for network and DOM activity to 'settle' and it's a reasonable approach for measuring SPAs

Another approach would be to instrument the SPA with User Timing marks and measures and beacon those somewhere.

Probably also worth looking at Elastic's RUM solution - came from OpBeat which I've used with Angular apps before - it's opensource so you can try before you buy (if you need to)

Answer (score 0):

The most recommended way is run **Google Lighthouse** from your chrome dev tools.

- open **devTools**
- Go to **Audits**
- Run **Audits**

You will see detailed performance metric there.

Even you check inertial load time in network tab at the bottom to see how much time it is taking all assets on first page load.

Comment: Hi @sakhi as this is a spa, google lighthouse will not work here, as when ever page is getting refreshed it will take user to home page, so we will only be able to see performance of home page not other pages.